# How to make the back function and set the last contentView

Tags: android, android-view

I hawe many view's in my application and now the problem is how to go back from one view to another.

What I could do it by set back Buttons in every view but i would like to use the android back hard button.

I have tried something like this:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{       
  if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
          {
      finish();
          }
return false;
}
```

But the problem is that this will close my application.
Could you please guide me for a  proper solution, for example to memorize the last view was set and then to come back to this view or something like this.

Here is the code with which I am changing the view (it's a method in my main activity):

```
public void CheckIfUserIsLogedIn ()
{
    int userPresence = localDatabase.CheckUserPresence();
    if (userPresence == 0) 
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
    else
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.userlogedon);
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Means you want show previous view on back button?

Comment: Are you finishing the current activity while moving to next activity ? Please put the code with which you are starting the new or next activity.

Comment: I edited my question @iDroid Explorer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look!

You are doing this wrong way..

An `Activity` class should only have on content `View`. (because it is recommended way and easy to use and implement).

And if you want to go to next `View`, show it under another separate `Activity`.

when you will finish it, you will be automatically redirected to previous `Activity`.

(and you don't need to **memorize** the Previous View :) )

[See here](http://www.warriorpoint.com/blog/2009/05/24/android-how-to-switch-between-activities/), how to work with `Activity` Stacks.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Adil, Ok so if I understand, I have to use a different class for every View i have?

Comment: @Ana: Yes. If you want to show say a Login view the you should have a `LoginActivity` which will show your `R.layout.userlogedon` as content view. Happy coding! Cheers! :)

Comment: @Ana: Yes. You should have to use the different activity for all respective View.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure to understand your problem correctly because Android do all that for you automatically. Once a view is opened when you switch to another view it is paused (on screen but has not focus) or stopped (has no focus)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

If the current view (activity) has been launched by the previous view (activity), pressing the back button will make you "close" the current view and go back to the previous one automatically.

Now two things :

1. Perhaps your are simply opening all views wihtin the same activity by showing on or off components which is a bad way of doing and is not recommended by android. What you should do is 1 view = 1 activity.
2. You are thinking like "iPhone/iPad" where you have to implements back buttons in the "views". In android you don't need to do so. Putting the "finish" command in your code at that point seem to close the application which make me think you have programmed as explained in point 1.

Hope it helps

**EDIT**:

To start a new activity do it like this

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, MyOtherActivity.class));
```

you put this in your code where you want to load the new view (activity)

Now if you want to transfer some information between activities you must do something like this :

```
Intent myIntent; //intent declaration

int aNumber = 10; // info to send to other activity
String aString = "abcd"; // info to send to other activity

// link Intent to the other activity
myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), MyOtherActivity.class) 

//put the extra info
myIntent.putExtra("myNumber", aNumber);
myIntent.putExtra("myString", aString);

//start the new view/activity
startActivity(myIntent);
```

and in the new opened activity you retrieve the infos like this (in the oncreate usually)

```
int aNumber;
String aString;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    aNumber= getIntent().getExtras().getInt("myNumber");
    aString= getIntent().getExtras().getString("myString"); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you @HpTeam, yes, you're right, I have one activity for all my views. I will try to change this.

Answer (score 0):

Actually i m not sure that understand exactly but..

take a map or a shared preference and at the back button set last View on map or Shared preference .

At the calling or at start activity fetch the data which have stored you.

this will helps you.